# Shimano a410 compatible brifters

Tags: shifter

Which brifters are compatible with Shimano RX100-A410 2x7 drivetrain?

Microshift SB-R472s perhaps?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can basically use any 7 speed Shimano brifter except for 7 speed dura-ace (which had a different cable pull). All the 7 speed Shimano rear derailleurs (road/mountain) except of dura-ace have the same cable pull. And you're fine with road front derailleur compatibility within Shimano.

The current Shimano brifter that is compatible is the Shimano ST-A070, from the Tourney line. The Microshift SB-R472 also works.

Comment: The Microshift is probably the better of the shifters, though the Tourney one is probably easier to get your mitts on.

Comment: I can get both on eBay: Microshift for cca. 50 €, Tourney for 70 €. I think I will try Microshift for a change.

Comment: The pricing will depend a lot on your market. In the US, the Microshift is more expensive than the Tourney.